# Найти мешающий скрипт

Tags: jquery, javascript

Часто сталкиваюсь с проблемой - например есть десять .js скриптов, один из них мешает работе второго. Но ошибку выдает только второй, как можно отыскать виновника торжества (не удаляя из index.php поочередно методом перебора).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать debugger.

**Firefox** - [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

**Opera[12-]** 
    - Встроенный DragonFly (*ПКМ* -> *Просмотр кода елемента*)

Chrome, Chromium, Opera[15+] и все, что на базе webkit 
    - встроенный инспектор (*Ctrl+Shift+J* или *ПКМ* -> *Просмотр кода елемента*)

IE - стыдно признатся, но я им не пользуюсь для дебага :D